# Current url multilanguage

Tags: php, url

I have the following code:

```
public function UrlLang() {
if ( (!isset($_REQUEST['lang'])) || (isset($_REQUEST['lang']) && ($_REQUEST['lang'] == 'es' || $_REQUEST['lang'] == 'ES')) ) {
        $Url = SITE_URL .'en/' . array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    } else {
        $Url = SITE_URL .'' . array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    }
        return $Url;
    }
```

The code returns the current url me, the problem is that if my url is not in the root url not work for me.

example:

http: // localhost / My_Cms_Db /
It works well.

http: //localhost/My_Cms_Db/nosotros.php
It works well.

http: //localhost/My_Cms_Db/nosotros/index.php
It does not work well.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: What should be the URL for 'en' and 'es' pages, can you please give example for both for any single page and also tell what is in SITE_URL?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your UrlLang() function with below code and try:

```
public function UrlLang() {

    $Url = str_replace(SITE_URL.'en/',SITE_URL,$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lang']))
    {
        $selectedLang = strtolower($_REQUEST['lang']);
        if($selectedLang=='es')
        {
            $Url = str_replace(SITE_URL,SITE_URL.'en/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    }

    return $Url;

}
```